# Too many connected disks to AKS node

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I read that there is a limitation to the amount of data disks that can bound to a node in a cluster. Right now im using a small node which can only hold up to 4 data disks. If i exceed this amount i will get this error: `0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) exceed max volume count.`

The question that i mainly have is how to handle this. I have some apps that just need a small amount of persistant storage in my cluster however i can only attach a few data disks. If i bind 4 data disks of 100m i already reached the max limit.

Could someone advice me on how to handle these scenarios? I can easily scale up the machines and i will have more power in my machine and more disks however the ratio disks vs server power is completely offset at that point.

Best
Pim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using Azure File instead of Azure Disk.  With Azure File, you can do ReadWriteMany hence having a single mount on the VM(node) to allow multiple POD to access the mounted volume.

https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/azure_file/README.md

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#azure-file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv

Comment: Though I was just unsuccessful in quickly finding the corresponding GitHub issue, I'm pretty sure there is one that describes pretty strong performance issues with AKS and Azure Files. Just FYI

Answer (score 0):

- 4 PV per node
- 30 pods per node

Thoses are the limits on AKS nodes right now.
You can handle it by add more nodes, and more money, or find a provider with different limits. 
On one of those, as an example, the limits are 127 volumes and 110 pods, for the same node size.

Comment: those are all configurable.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/quotas-skus-regions#service-quotas-and-limits with Azure CNI it's 250 pods per node assuming have you enough IPs or 110 with Kubenet.

Comment: the number of PV is defined by each node type